# Where can I find a good tutorial for stochastic modeling using Mathematica?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions, markov-chains, education

I am a newbie in Mathematica and I aim to use Mathematica mostly for stochastic modeling (to develop and analyze models in evolutionary biology). Note that I am not necessarily a great mathematician yet $\ddot \smile$. I am NOT interested about data analysis and statistics (I usually use R for this purpose) but only about stochastic modeling.

**Where can I find good and free ressources (online tutorial, videos, ...) on how to use Mathematica for stochastic modeling?**

---

Note I already asked a bunch of questions on this site that concern stochastic modeling like [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/63826/what-is-the-pdf-of-a-variable-where-a-parameter-is-itself-a-random-variable/63833?noredirect=1#comment179235_63833) and [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/63749/function-of-a-random-variable). The two posts already received very good answers but those posts are the kind of questions I amy want to receive answers to by looking at a tutorial.

Comment: When I google "stochastic modeling tutorial" I get a bunch of information that is useful (which I would classify as good).  Not sure what you are looking for here (and whether or not this question is better suited for Mathematics.SE).

Comment: @bobthechemist I am looking for a tutorial on how to use Mathematica to develop and analyze stochastic models. My question is specific to Mathematica that's why googling "stochastic modeling tutorial" does not yield to what I am looking for and that's why my question is, I think, on-topic. I think the point is clear in my question but not in the title maybe. So I edited my title to add "using Mathematica". Let me know if you still think my question is unclear or off-topic. I think having a look to the two links may help making an idea of the kind of questions I am seeking answers to. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good source are the Wolfram.com pages;

[http://mathworld.wolfram.com/search/?query=stochastic+models&x=17&y=14](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/search/?query=stochastic%20models&x=17&y=14)

[http://search.wolfram.com/?query=stochastic+models&x=0&y=0](http://search.wolfram.com/?query=stochastic%20models&x=0&y=0)

Not free, but gives you a good overview for the library;

http://www.wolfram.com/books/search.html?libraryquery=stochastic&collection=books&topic=&language=&x=0&y=0

At least, but not forgotten:

[https://www.google.ch/search?hl=de&as_q=Mathematica+tutorial+for+stochastic+modeling&as_epq=&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&lr=&cr=&as_qdr=all&as_sitesearch=&as_occt=any&safe=images&as_filetype=pdf&as_rights=](https://www.google.ch/search?hl=de&as_q=Mathematica%20tutorial%20for%20stochastic%20modeling&as_epq=&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&lr=&cr=&as_qdr=all&as_sitesearch=&as_occt=any&safe=images&as_filetype=pdf&as_rights=)